# Generic Types in Typescript Cannot be used to index object

Tags: typescript, generics, casting

I am trying to create to type my class with generics and it alays throws me an error

```
class CustomDataStructure<T> {
    public _data: object;

     constructor() {
        this._data = {};
        }
    public getAndDeleteRandomKey(): void {
        const allExistingKeys = Object.keys(this._data);
        const randomKey = allExistingKeys[Math.floor(Math.random()*(allExistingKeys.length))];
        this.removeItem(randomKey);
    }
   
    public addItem(value: T): void {
        console.log("adding");
        console.log(this._data)
        this._data[value] = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public removeItem(key: T): void {
        delete this._data[key];
    }
}

let ss = new CustomDataStructure<string>();
ss.addItem("hello");
ss.addItem("hello2");
```

This throws me 2 different errors

1. parameter of type 'T'.'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
2. Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'object'

am i missing anything here

[TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgETEsBlJATvMEvAQKYA8AKgHzQDeAUNK9AA7wBGIAlsNAD6AE2xgAXNBRcAVuRIBuJizbRgKAHbIiJFAQAUASkYrVrJAAteEAHQix0ALyMAvkrNsXpjtz4CA5uRIAIIawhjkIEHkAEpgYegA0uQAnkaSAG4ovMImHqzqWkjQYCAgAKIAHtZIvBr+ySkwzgDysvJINgDWqRD6ltZ2ojiG7vmFyNAE8cJJqU4lZVU1dQ29ANoAstgWNgBmICh6+tuWNtMJaEYAVPqlFdXIq422UfWWhoYAumMeA7YUNAoDLkACSSHIVwuszQjVG3i8bG8nB4-BKwmE4Mh+gypXg5Ek1EMmWyuWY+TUmggKCiNkO-n0ACIwBjVoz4RSJjTyHSUAz-kMxIZvKoBfYcOtcSB8V8FhpyAB3aBYCFGGyBJDUXhochGX7QLzI3xowHAsEQq49FKE4nQLI5PL5YSRaLQMXDMDrK0-BFMQ1RYpQOWKuCIVCYMT4HSkCiUbSrWh6phQGwszEWpkWSKHdlKFNprFXRlZsooABMuaAA)

Comment: Why are you using a generic type here? What other possible types would you use to key your data object?

Comment: Keys can be numbers as well

Comment: They can, but ultimately under the hood they get cast to string.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the generic T could be also a complex object, e.g. a class instance and you only can use primitive objects as key

```
const object = {}
object["myKey"] = true // works 
object[new Date()] = true // not works, because is a complex object
```

consider using a map, see

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgETEsBlJATvMEvAQKYA8AKgHzQDeAUNK9AA4ECWAbtudAD6AE2xgAXNACyYdjQA00MADsAnvQC80ZeQDu02QAoAlAG4mLNtGAplyIiRQETjAL6XW7eACMQXYNAA5uRIAILKwhjkICHkAEoqwugA0uSqJpI8KFzCjB5W1rbISiAgAKIAHlzIXMqBqaowWqEEBGCqAHQAZgTohkgAFtUdImIdANZpECZm%20VY2dkjQbREpadBaYKWV1Ui19VMA2jKD3SAoToYnAx0rSWgmAFSGW%20VVNXUNEB0xdYPGxgAuuYCmxBsNRjgOsJorFDHc1qpZlZ3Gx8l5fP4lMJhABJJDkB58EDwciSajGTLZXLMUGscHfSFgDoQEKGYmkxQ6fRYAkmDrBJDULhocgzfLuCySmJLKAbbR6OCIVCYMT4BykCiUez7WgmcxQDpgHH4wmGABEA2i53Ns0NxrxBIelutKAATLbTEA)

```js
class CustomDataStructure<T> {
    private _data: Map<T, any> = new Map();

     constructor() {}
    public getAndDeleteRandomKey(): void {
        const allExistingKeys = Array.from(this._data.keys());
        const randomKey = allExistingKeys[Math.floor(Math.random()*(allExistingKeys.length))];
        this._data.delete(randomKey);
    }
   
    public addItem(value: T): void {
        this._data.set(value, new Date().getTime())
    }


}

let ss = new CustomDataStructure<string>();
ss.addItem("hello");
ss.addItem("hello2");
```